# VS2008 and Crystal Reports - Deployment restrictions?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, crystal-reports

I'm looking for experiences with deploying Crystal reports (the basic version, bundled with VS2008) into a production environment.

Are there any restrictions?  Does it limit the number of concurrent users?  Other than downloading and installing the CRRedist2008_x86.msi on the production server, anything to worry about?

(And judging from the comments here and other places, yes it would be better to find another solution, but unless there's something free that works with VS2008/IIS6, we're stuck with it for now).

Answer (score 1):

Sooner or later you will get introduced to the "The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached." error. You can get around it by cycling the application pool for the site more frequently, but if it's heavily used, you'll eventually want to look at Crystal Enterprise Server.

Comment: I've looked around to see what that limit might be, but can't seem to locate anything that specifies the hard limits. I even tried searching with bing :)  Any pointers?

Comment: I seem to remember the errors showing up after somewhere around 75 executions. Concurrent executions didn't cause a problem other than a performance hit on big reports.